# Computing a Weighted AUC Metric

Tags: mathematical-statistics, classification, roc

Consider the standard ROC-AUC metric, which has been shown to be equivalent to the normalized Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney:
$$
AUC = \frac{1}{N^{(+)}N^{(-)}} \sum_{i}\sum_{j}1[\hat{p}_i^{(+)} > \hat{p}_j^{(-)}]
$$
where $\hat{p}^{(+)}, \hat{p}^{(-)}$ are the estimated probabilities for positive ($y=1$) and negative outcomes ($y=0$), $1[.]$ is indicator function, and $N^{(+)}, N^{(-)}$ are the number of positive and negative samples.

Suppose that we wished to focus more on a specific region of the ROC curve by emphasizing either the positive outcomes, or on the negative outcomes. Is there a way to add label weights into this metric (e.g. weight the positive labels higher)?